# NSWindowStyleMaskBorderless not borderless in macOS 12.x

Tags: objective-c, macos, nswindow

I have an [NSWindowStyleMaskBorderless](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindowstylemask/nswindowstylemaskborderless) enumeration property set for an NSWindow:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    
    [self window].backgroundColor = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedWhite:0.5 alpha:1.0];
    [self.window setStyleMask:NSWindowStyleMaskBorderless];

}
```

Yet, there's a thin black border around the entire window — is there no way to remove it? ffs

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? I seem to be unable to remove the borders from my view. It only works for me if I set `window.hasShadow = false`.

Comment: @j.unruh, I reported to Apple Jul 19, 2022. They asked me if it was fixed in macOS 13 Beta 10 (22A5365d) on Oct 7, 2022. The answer was `no` and zero response since.

Comment: My approach now has been to give the shadow to the (SwiftUI) content of the window and set `window.hasShadow = false`. This works for me. So in your case I assume it might make sense to fill the window with a proper background, give the background a shadow and then disable the shadow on the window itself.

Comment: @j.unruh, Indeed turning the shadow off does get rid of the border, although then you also lose the window shadow unfortunately. Your suggestion probably would work, however, it seems like a lot of redoing windows for something that function as it did before.